# Difference between hierarchical dirichlet process and nested dirichlet process

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, dirichlet-distribution, dirichlet-process

There have some extensions to Dirichlet process. One is Hierarchical Dirichlet process, and another is Nested Dirichlet Process. What are the differences between these two?

I once read the paper of [Bayesian Nonparametric Inference -- Why and How](http://ba.stat.cmu.edu/journal/2013/vol08/issue02/mueller.pdf). The author discusses their differences as follows, but I am not clear how to understand this. Any more explanations is highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Try looking at the Chinese restaurant process representations of them.  For me, at least, those representations provide a lot of intuition.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot post a comment with a Figure, so bear with me...

In the NDP manuscript there is a great figure that let me understand exactly what is going on:

[image]

In the HDP, different groups are modelled with different mixing distributions (i.e. $P(G_1 = G_2) = 0$) that however share the same set of atoms.

In the NDP different groups are modelled with a Dirichlet Process, meaning that different groups can have the same mixing distribution (i.e $P(G_1 = G_2) > 0$), as in happens in the figure for $G_1$ and $G_3$.

However, if two measures are different, they are completely different (weights and atoms), in contrast with the HDP for which the atoms are equal.

Answer (score 0):

For HDP, $G_j$ are samples from a discrete distribution $G_0=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\pi_k\delta_{\theta_k}$, with i.i.d. atoms $\theta_k$ from base measure $H$.

For NDP, $G_j$ are samples from $Q$, which is a little complicated. $Q$ is a sample from a $DP$, whose base measure is another Dirichlet Process $DP(\beta, H)$. Therefore, by definition, $Q=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\pi_k\delta_{G_k^*}$, where the i.i.d. atoms $G_k^*$ are drawn from the $DP(\beta, H)$. In other words, $Q$ is a distribution, with probability mass over samples from a DP. As $G_j\sim Q$, the samples $G_j$ can only be equal to one of the samples from the inner $DP$, i.e. one of the atoms $G_k^*$.